# Невалидный итератор после поиска

Tags: c++, функции, segmentation-fault, итераторы, lazyloading

Мне нужен класс в котором одно из полей(контейнер) будет подгружаться по мере необходимости. Например когда происходит вызов begin() данные подгрузятся.

Так же у меня есть шаблонная функция поиска, в которой я использую std::find_if, но с ней не хочет дружить отложенная загрузка.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class my_storage
{
public:
    using container = std::vector<std::string>;
    using iterator = container::iterator;

    iterator begin()
    {
        m_container.push_back("Mike");
        m_container.push_back("John");
        m_container.push_back("David");
        return m_container.begin();
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return m_container.end();
    }
private:
    container m_container {};
};



template<class T>
typename T::iterator find_David(T& storage)
{
    auto find_lambda {[](const std::string& element)
                      {
                          return element == "David";
                      }};

    return std::find_if(storage.begin(), storage.end(),
                        find_lambda); // с этим итератором будет segmentation fault

    auto begin {storage.begin()};
    return std::find_if(begin, storage.end(), find_lambda); // а так работает
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    my_storage storage {};

    auto david_it {find_David(storage)};

    if (david_it != storage.end()) {

        std::cout << "David exists" << std::endl;   
        std::cout << *david_it  << std::endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это описание ситуации, а не вопрос :)

А вообще, порядок построения аргументов функции не определен, так что у вас, вероятно, в

```
return std::find_if(storage.begin(), storage.end(),
```

сначала вычисляется `storage.end()` (для пустого контейнера), а уже потом `storage.begin()` (который, добавляя элементы в контейнер, инвалидизирует итератор, возвращенный `storage.end()`).

В то время как во втором варианте, понятно, порядок обратный, там `storage.begin()` точно вызывается первым..

Answer (score 1):

Порядок выполнения аргументов функции не определен, и в

```
std::find_if(storage.begin(), storage.end(),
```

сначала может выполниться `end()`, а потом `begin()`.

И всё бы хорошо, но у Вас `begin()` изменяет контейнер и инвалидирует `end()`.